# How can I Make Single Application for web and desktop in JAVA

Tags: java, web, javafx, cross-platform, desktop

I need to make a cross platform application than can run on MAC, Windows, Linux and also on web. Can JAVA be used for this? If yes then what type of JAVA project and what architecture should I use? And also need to implement MVC.

My Application will store data on local pc and will also have same interface on web. And both platforms will keep in sync!

Comment: Yes. A regular Java project. Not sure about MVC.

Comment: so SWING can be used on web ?

Comment: yes Java Swing can be used on the web. Here is a helpful article from Oracle written in 2006: [Swing or JavaServer Faces:Which to choose?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/nimphius-mills-swing-jsf-092891.html)

Comment: I hope people aren't thinking about applets. You could create a WebStart program, so people can start it from the web, but it would run as a desktop software.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Article from 2006, come on.

Comment: @Kayaman :) he wanted to know about Swing, which has been around since 1998, so 2006 is relatively recent compared to 1998.

Comment: Ok. i was also thing on applets but was not sure. @Kayaman WebStart project can run independently on desktop pc ?

Comment: @Mian.Ammar Don't bother with applets. They weren't a very good idea 10 years ago, and they certainly aren't something that people use today (not to mention the Java plugin is often disabled due to security issues). A WebStart application is just like a regular Swing app, except you can download and start it with a single click.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks. I can be wrong also but was thinking that i develop application for desktop and then same application can be deployed on web and they both sync there databases on local pc and remote web server !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices are somewhat as follows.

- Create a remote server
- Create a Swing desktop client
- Use the Swing client through Web Start **or** create a separate web
  client on the remote server (with any frameworks of your choice).

Obviously the choice without a separate web client is simpler, but it also means that all "web" users must have Java installed and Web Start must be allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes java is best fit for this....about project type first of all decide the frameworks you are going to use.

Comment: Like for MVC spring is best,but for orm what are your requirement.

Comment: Yes then you can go for spring-mvc and spring orm so that you canutilize in built support of spring-orm for using mysql.  Refer these link   http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/jpaorm/spring-hibernate-mysql-and-maven-showcase/                                                            http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/